# How to map a lambda function to variable that can be a float, int, or list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

I'm trying to map a lambda function to variable that can be a float, int, or list.

**Test #1**, this works:

```
val = [0.1]
test =  list(map(lambda x: max(x, 1 - x), val))
```

**Test #2**, this throws `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`:

```
val = 0.1
test =  list(map(lambda x: max(x, 1 - x), val))
```

I tried to solve it with `list(val)` (that is, `list(map(lambda x: max(x, 1 - x), list(val)))`), but it throws the same error.

**How can I get it to work in both Test #1 and Test #2?** Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this case using if condition inside your map function. Try like this:

```
val = 0.1
test = list(map(lambda x: max(x, 1 - x), val if isinstance(val, list) else [val]))
```

it will handle your all cases like list, int and decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error, because in **Test #2** `val` variable is not iterable (because it's a float value), so `map()` function has no object to iterate through.

The `map()` function applies a given function to each item of an iterable (list, tuple etc.) and returns an iterator.

Update:

Here is the solution working for both Tests:

```py
val = 0.1
test =  list(map(lambda x: max(x, 1 - x), [val] if type(val) != list else val))
```

If the type of `val` variable is not a list, then we convert it to be a list; otherwise, we leave the `val` variable without conversion.

Alternatively, you can do it like that (for Test #2):

```py
val = 0.1
test =  list(map(lambda x: max(x, 1 - x), [val]))
```

Comment: That returns an error for Test #1 `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'`

Comment: Yes, because in Test #1 you already have an array, that you can iterate through. My solution only applies to Test #2.

Comment: @a11 I updated my solution to work with both Tests now